# How (and whether) to flag a post with an irrelevant picture

Tags: discussion, flagging, images

[This post](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/365458/1) made me think of the question. This particular question is either a learner's question better suited for ELL, or a low-quality question. It made me think of the question of whether irrelevant images should be flagged, in questions or answers that are otherwise acceptable, and if so, what the appropriate flag is. Is it spam? That is, should the posting of an irrelevant work of art be considered promotion of that work of art, or of the user as an artist? I did not see anything in the flagging process that jumped out at me, except the possibility of "in need of moderator intervention."

Comment: The birthday question so bad that the much-too-large picture is just....irrelevant. I don't remember seeing an irrelevant picture in an otherwise relevant question or answer on ELU, but I came relatively recently. This, http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/880/is-the-large-picture-necessary, is related to your question. The picture was a good illustration in an intriguing answer, but originally much too large.   (I haven't done the numbers on the answer, so I don't know if it would work.)

Comment: @ab2, interesting link. It looks from the revision history like they've gone back and forth a few times between the ginormous picture and a scaled-down one.

Comment: I would have edited it out, not because I don't like fun, but because that picture is totally useless. Would have left a comment about why I did it as well, then moved on. Rollback wars are tedious, and if you see one, that does deserve a flag (needs moderator intervention).  Spam has a distinct definition with regard to flags; it's not used quite like many people use the word.

Comment: @medica that was my first thought as well, though since I'm new to the group I thought I would check first. On second thought I see no reason why I shouldn't have just axed that puppy. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I see some blatantly irrelevant picture, text, or link in an otherwise okay post, my first choice would be to edit it out. I'd also maybe kindly let the user know why I did that.

And then if I see a potential for an edit war, I'd definitely flag it for a moderator's attention.

On the other hand, if I see that a post is itself not relevant for ELU's audience, with and without the attached irrelevant picture or spammy link, I'd choose some other flags.