# What if an image was used to answer the question I've provided below?

Tags: discussion

The answer by [FumbleFingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers) to the question [Term for offering something just out of reach](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380276/term-for-offering-something-just-out-of-reach/380282?noredirect=1#comment897891_380282) evokes too many images.

[image: Dangling a carrot]

Adding an image may help an answer by replacing few or all of the words. It also helps anyone remember it for a long time. I've done it a few times. Got a great response. But I am capricious and I couldn't resist adding a visual aid.

So my question is how much help would it be if the image provided above was used as an answer for the mentioned question ?

Comment: Oh dear! Noting the downvotes you're getting here, I kinda regret suggesting you could ask about this on meta! But I don't really understand (or agree with) them, to be honest. The question seems relevant and well-posed, so I've upvoted on that basis. And you've carefully avoided framing your question so it would be justifiable for people to downvote purely because they don't want images in ELU answers - you're only asking what they think, not whether they disagree with what *you* [might] think. And the closevote citing POB just seems nonsensical on a meta question tagged "discussion".

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, but I'm just a little user so I'll comment instead of answer, that a picture does not answer the question.  What if I had not heard the term and saw that picture?  Nothing.  On our other SE sites picture-only answers are highly discouraged.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes a picture is very helpful. But the answer should contain an explanation also.

Picture-only answers are strongly discouraged. [Irrelevant pictures are not welcome](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9914/50044), and may be removed by other users.

An example is the [following answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/308144/50044) to a question I once posted. It explains well, and the added picture is very helpful.

[image: This is an accepted answer with 41 score and an image of what appears to be a batter riding a horse with a carrot on a stick in the crook of his arm, and a baseball bat spanking the horse's buttocks. The text of the answer reads: "Here, *the carrots* refer to attractive features that might lure you into adopting the new version. It comes from the idiom *carrot and stick*. To induce someone to do something you can promise as a reward, the carrot, threaten punishment, the *stick*, or do both. There's an analogy here trying to make a horse or donkey go forward. Thanks to Todd Wilcox for the picture suggestion." The artist's signature, and a publication date of 2013 is to our lower right, but I can't quite make it out. It looks like Dave Contu.]

Comment: Nice one. I notice that your 'quote' is itself a picture.